# Проблема с position в css

Tags: вёрстка, css

Не пойму, почему в редакторе показывает одно расстояние между блоками, а в браузерах совсем другое... На фото подробно видно. Заранее спасибо.

Разместил фото здесь:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Код:

```
.okno1{width:290px;
       height:235px;
       border:2px solid;
       border-color:#66CCCC;
       background-color: #FFFF99;
       margin:5% 0% 0% 11%;



       }
.okno1 ul{ line-height:25px; 
           list-style-type: none;
           padding-left:25px

}
.okno1 img{ padding:3px;}

.okno1 h3{text-align: center;
          }
.okno2{
    width:290px;
    height:236px;
    border:2px solid;
    border-color:#66CCCC;
    margin:0%;
    position:absolute;
    right:400PX;
    top:200PX;

}
```

Comment: Вот сайт, там находим почему: [сайт][1]


В поисковике ищем статьи на тему кроссбраузерность, также идём на [htmlbook][2]


  [1]: http://www.xiper.net/
  [2]: http://htmlbook.ru/

и учим html/css.

Comment: та уже выучил многое...просмотрел видео курсы и в htmlbook  тоже поглядываю постоянно,но проблему не могу решить(

Comment: Я, конечно, извиняюсь, но только по этим первым стилям:

    border:2px solid;    
    border-color:#66CCCC;    
    margin:5% 0% 0% 11%;

я могу точно сказать ,что вы про CSS знаете не так уж и много.Я тоже только начинающий в верстке и посмотрев пару уроков CSS думал, что я уже его выучил, а когда дошло до дела оказалось, что я ничего и не знаю-то. Советую вам как минимум пройти еще несколько курсов других авторов и почитать статьи про CSS, ну и последнее писать код руками, а не в редакторе.





Answer (score 2):

Проверять отображение сайта в IDE не стоит. Сайт всегда тестируют в браузере. Только так можно проверить правильность отображения сайта. Лучше тестировать в последних версиях всех браузеров. Не стоит доверять встроенному движку IDE. Я столкнулся в свое время с этой же проблемой.

Я делаю так. В IDE сначала пишу код, примерно смотрю как визуализируется в встроенном движке. Потом запускаю в FireFox и с помощью FireBug правлю вживую, смотрю что меняется. Все изменения переношу в среду разработки. После этого смотрю в остальных браузерах последних версий. Отдельно смотрю в IE9, в нем проблем с отображением нет. В нем же есть средство разработчика с возможностью включить режим IE8 и IE7. В нем же можно внести в код изменения, чтобы понять, что нужно исправить. В IE6 не смотрю.

Для задач верстки такого способа будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам правильно ответили. Так как в каждом браузере размер пикселя разный. К примеру даже на самую малость. под каждый браузер надо подстраивать. Можете попробовать в %.

Comment: да,я в курсе...даже в % не помогает-я пробовал конечно же.

Comment: Вам надо тот желтый блок опустить?

Comment: нет.мне надо одинаковое расстояние между блоками.что бы как в редакторе так и в браузере отображалось.У меня на данный момент криво везде.

Comment: margin в помощь, LOL

Comment: спасибо кэп!

Comment: Можно более сделать по человечески юрзать таблицы

Comment: дельный совет!спасибо

Answer (score 0):

для начала хотя бы используйте [reset.css](http://www.xiper.net/collect/services/build-reset-css.html)